# Debugging flutter: How to force VSCode asking for device every time?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode to debug my flutter apps. Hitting **F5** I start debugging - and initially it lets me (usually) pick the device (chrome, android emulator etc). If I stop it and hit F5 again, it does not ask me anymore...

Furthermore, there must be some hierarchy between devices. If I have for example my phone connected through usb, it automatically picks it for debugging even if I have my emulator up and running. With flutter 2, now it always picks Chrome...

This behavior is super annoying...

How can I force VS Code to **always** ask me which device to pick?

If that is not possible, how can I edit this hierarchy to pick for example the emulator over the device connected through usb?

Comment: When you choose the device on the buttom right, I think it will always default to that. Might be for the VS code session but I don't have this issue. I see chrome now because of Flutter 2 but you can choose the device then it defaults to it when you debug

Comment: This feature would be extremely helpful. I debug with physical devices and emulators. I have multiple instances of VS Code open at the same time and assign a device for that program to debug on. Unplugging the physical device, causes one of the emulators to be selected (obviously), but when I plug it back in, it stays with the emulator. Would just be nice to have VS Code ask you every time which device it should use to debug on.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to force it to ask each time (though you could [file an issue here](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code) for consideration), but you could disable the [dart.flutterSelectDeviceWhenConnected](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/#dartflutterselectdevicewhenconnected) setting to prevent it switching to a newly-connected phone when there's already a selected device.